# problems with UDP snmp client Java

Tags: java, snmp, udpclient

I'm writing an snmp client that connects to a network server via UDP port 161. It will send an ASN formatted message and will receive the response from the server. I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to get it working properly.

The program is supposed to receive and parse out the counter field returned from the following command in cmd:

snmpget -d -v 2c -c public 129.130.10.43 ip.ipInReceives.0

//result of command:

{

Sending 43 bytes to UDP: [129.130.10.43]:161->[0.0.0.0]

0000: 30 29 02 01  01 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A0 1C 02    0).....public...

0016: 04 28 6A DF  1F 02 01 00  02 01 00 30  0E 30 0C 06    .(j........0.0..

0032: 08 2B 06 01  02 01 04 03  00 05 00                    .+.........

Received 47 bytes from UDP: [129.130.10.43]:161->[0.0.0.0]

0000: 30 2D 02 01  01 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A2 20 02    0-.....public. .

0016: 04 28 6A DF  1F 02 01 00  02 01 00 30  12 30 10 06    .(j........0.0..

0032: 08 2B 06 01  02 01 04 03  00 41 04 1B  49 0C 95       .+.......A..I..

IP-MIB::ipInReceives.0 = Counter32: 457772181

}

//my asn message formatting notes:

hex values to save in a byte[] array and pass to the udp server:

30 29 02 01  01 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A0 1C 02

04 XX XX XX  XX 02 01 00  02 01 00 30  0E 30 0C 06

08 2B 06 01  02 01 04 03  00 05 00

XX's indicate the request ID 
XX's will be changed (probably randomized) for each request in order to create a unique Request ID

Code:

```
  public static void snmpMessage() throws SocketException
{
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    byte[] serverResponse = new byte[1024];
    InetAddress addy = null;        
    byte[] hex = hexStringToByteArray("302902010004067075626C6963A01C0204121533EA020100020100300E300C06082B060102010403000500"); //note: this hex string is the exact string from the example program, so I know the string is correct
    addy = InetAddress.getByName("129.130.10.48"); //server IP address
    socket= new DatagramSocket();

    //method that creates unique snmp asn message replacing the XX's with appropriate non-negative hex values       
    hex = messageGenerator();

    //Data reproduction from byte[] array
    System.out.println("byte array integer format:\n" + Arrays.toString(hex)); //correctly prints out integer values        
    System.out.println("\nbyte array length: " + hex.length); //Correctly prints length of sending array (43)
    System.out.println("\nserver name: " + addy.getCanonicalHostName()); //correctly prints server name        
    String hex2 = toHex(hex);        
    System.out.println("\nbyte array in hex format: \n" + hex2); //correctly reproduces original hex string from byte[] array

    //at this point, I can only assume that my data is stored correctly
    //send byte array to server
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(hex, hex.length, addy, 161);
        socket.send(sendPacket);                

    //get server's response
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(serverResponse, serverResponse.length);       
        System.out.println("\nWaiting for server response...\n"); //prints out
        socket.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("Response received"); //does not print
}
```

My professor has posted an example where he simply passes the pointer to a char string:
sendto (sockfd, (char *) s, 43, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, servlen);
His code that passes the same hex code works perfectly.

The only thing I can think of is that I'm not formatting, sending, or listening correctly, but after pouring over documentation and examples, I can't figure anything out. Does anyone have some pointers?

Comment: If you have access to your professor's example, try running it, along with your own, and use a tool like Wireshark, or tcpdump, to see what's actually being sent out on the wire, in both cases.  You can see what your program is sending differently, if anything is being sent out at all.

Comment: I have to run the prof's example remotely through putty on a linux server and I don't know of a way to get wireshark on that. I did a capture on my outgoing packet and everything looks perfectly correct (destination is good, port is 161, message body is good, etc), but I don't get any response from the server in wireshark. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: You can try tcpdump on the Linux server.  It's not as user-friendly, but it's still very simple.  A quick google or look over the man page for it will tell you how to use it.

Comment: Apparently, there's a problem converting my HEX string to byte[], but my packet is getting shipped out to the proper place at least.

Edit - I am currently converting my hex string to byte[], then back to string again and comparing that against the original hex string and it matches, so I'm back at square 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you narrowed down your problem to the hex string to byte array conversion, here ya go:

**Converting a hex string to a byte array, in Java**

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that (notice my function call to that method) and it's incorrect. Some of my data bytes are being incorrectly converted with that method (though I'm not really sure why and at this point, I don't really care). I ended up just using 'DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);' to get the byte[] representation of a hex string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The method I was using to convert my hex string to byte[] wasn't working quite right. I switched to use the built-in converter "DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);" and it worked just fine.

Comment: When I run it on the server, I get some sort of response, but I can't seem to unpack it to make any sense of it. The machine doesn't seem to have tcpdump installed on it, so I'm having difficulty figuring out what's actually being sent in the packets. This is the output I'm getting:

'java.net.DatagramPacket@(7 or 8 char length hex string)' where the hex string appears to be randomized regardless if my message is unique or not

or

0)public*square*3*square*00
+
PuTTy

I can extract some sort of number using receivedPacket.getData().toString(), but it doesn't appear to be correct.